# How can one have a little music track listing that can drop down from an indicator applet?

Tags: indicator, vlc, music-player

I wanna play my sweet sweet slow jams but I ain't got no track listing in my VLC indicator applet drop-down in Unity on 16.04! Friendos, in all of this green and blue planet, how might this me done?

[image]

---

EDIT: When I try using the speaker drop-down menu with Rhythmbox, I don't see a track listing, only controls. I need to see like a listing of maybe 6 or so tracks, like 3 just played and 3 upcoming, something like that.

[image]

Comment: Do you simply want the currently playing song name to appear in the systray / application indicator notification area?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Hey there, no I need a track listing, like with 6 tracks nearby to the current one -- like listing the last 3 played and the next 3 upcoming.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use Rhythmbox Music Player (downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Centre) instead which should give you what you require.

After installing Rhythmbox, it is always present so you either open it or simply control it from the systembar at the top of the screen using the speaker icon dropdown by left clicking the speaker icon which allows you control of the player.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't see how to get Rhythmbox to appear as an indicator icon or to display a track listing from such an icon. It doesn't look promising from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/125224/how-do-i-hide-rhythmbox-to-just-show-a-tray-icon

Comment: @BlandCorporation You can control it from the systembar at the top using the speaker icon dropdown which allows you control of the player

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm looking to get an actual track listing, not just controls to pause and skip (I've edited my question to show what I'm seeing). I wanna see like the last 3 tracks played and the next 3, something like that.